# How to get data lattitude and longitude from parent activity class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have a class helper functions take the location of the GPS, I extend to the class activity. Then I had a class loader to display a splash screen and take the position of lattitude and longitude of class loader class helper, I extend to the helper class.
But how come when you first run always nullpointerexception?

This is the class loader and my helper class:

```
public class LocationHelper extends Activity {
private static LocationHelper mInstance = new LocationHelper();
private LatLng curlatlng;
private GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager locManager;
LocationListener locListener;
Location location;

public LocationHelper() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initLocationManager();
}

public static LocationHelper getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public LatLng getLocation() {
    return curlatlng;
}

public Location getLocationProvider() {
    return location;
}

private void initLocationManager() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                curlatlng = new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(),
                        mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("error", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }, 3000);

    locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locListener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            location = locManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        }

    };
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            locListener);
    location = locManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}}
```

This is LocationHelper :

```
 public class LocationAdapter extends LocationHelper {
 private LocationHelper helper = LocationHelper.getInstance();
 private LatLng userLocation;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_loader);
    splash_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_splash);

    new LoadDataTour().execute();

    public class LoadDataTour extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try { //i get error from here
            if (helper.getLocation() != null) {
                userLocation = helper.getLocation();
            } else if (helper.getLocationProvider() != null) {
                userLocation = new LatLng(helper.getLocationProvider()
                        .getLatitude(), helper.getLocationProvider()
                        .getLongitude());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error Get Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if (userLocation != null) {
                setLat(String.valueOf(userLocation.latitude));
                setLng(String.valueOf(userLocation.longitude));
                setLinkUrl(URL_WEB + "tabel=" + getTabel() + "&lat="
                        + getLat() + "&long=" + getLng());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error Get Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error get data position : " + ex.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: please specify which line has NPE

Comment: when application execute this code : userLocation = new LatLng(helper.getLocationProvider()
                        .getLatitude(), helper.getLocationProvider()
                        .getLongitude());

Comment: please post the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Where is

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

method in your async task? i think problem is that so there are null pointer exception generated... check it.
and one more thing to you declare async task with in onCreate method it should be out side any method..